# Without any reason MySQL usage goes down

Tags: mysql

Without any reason, my MySQL server hangs. For example, when I start my ubuntu server it works properly for the first 3hours then  MySQL server usage goes down. After that, I restart my server it will work properly for the first 3hours.. how to solve this issue?

Comment: You need to give more information about the version of your Ubuntu system, hardware specifications (esp. the amount of physical memory), and the amount of `free` memory when your MySQL server starts to hang.

Comment: **ubuntu version 18.04** ,instance type was **t2.medium**,mysql version **5.7.35** and we using mosquitto server to store the onmessage data to our database. Free memory **Mem:           3929         559         584           3        2785        3129**.  I created a new server for testing . I facing the same issue in that server

Comment: Please [edit] your original question to add the information you provided. This seems to be an AWS instance. You should know that AWS uses a CPU credit mechanism for t2 type instances. So you should watch your instance's CPU credits usage closely: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-monitoring-cpu-credits.html

Comment: There should be an explanation for MySQL failing in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`. If you are unsure of what the log is reporting, [edit] your question to contain the pertinent information and someone here may be able to help 

Comment: mysql usage downs time any errors not generated on mysql error logs

Comment: As someone who has used MySQL for 20+ years and seen just about every failure the software is capable of, I find it unlikely that the database engine can go down without a message unless: (1) it's not the MySQL failing, but the entire server (2) the EBS storage is 100% full and incapable of recording any more data, which would kill not only MySQL, but every service on the server. You will need to provide a great deal more *actionable* data if you would like people here to help, as none of us have access to your server to perform any checks for you 

Comment: There must be a reason. If you read (and posted, which would help us help you) the logs that are generated by MySQL, you would see the reason. 

Also, is there a setting that needs to be changed? It seems like you could have your MySQL server set to decrease it's usage after a few hours of uptime.